# Keep Docker running when shell script exits

Tags: nginx, docker

I have the following docker file.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
EXPOSE 9000:80

# Install nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

# Install Curl
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
ENTRYPOINT service nginx start
```

When I try to run the following commands in a shell script, the docker image is created
and container is started, however, when the shell script exits, the docker container is stopped.

How can I keep the docker container running after the shell script exits ? The idea is to have a running container with nginx running on port 80 that can be accessed from host using port 9000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run nginx as a background service. Launch it in the foreground as the nginx container on hub.docker.com does:

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

With containers, when pid 1 dies, your container dies. It's identical to when you kill pid 1 (init) on any Linux machine.

Comment: Call run with a `-d` after run but before your image name.